# Not rendering my image correctly

Tags: php, image, gd

I tried to make a captcha image rendering a random text (look at my `$_SESSION["captcha"]`).

It's working perfectly on my localhost with WAMP, but on my website it shows only a transparent 64x20 image, no text on, nothing.

I had an error 500 before and I installed php5-gd + restarted Apache, maybe I missed something to install?

I don't have access to my (error) logs.

Here is my code :

```
<?php

session_start();

$_SESSION["captcha"] = mt_rand(100, 999);
$img = imagecreatetruecolor(64, 20);
$font = "Inversionz.otf";

imagealphablending($img, true);
imagesavealpha($img, true);

imagefill($img, 0, 0, 0x7fff0000);
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);

imagettftext($img, 27, 0, 0, 20, $textcolor, $font, $_SESSION["captcha"]);

header("Content-type:image/png");
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);

?>
```

My font (Inversionz.otf) is uploaded.

Comment: Get access to those error logs, they'll tell you exactly what the problem is. Or maybe you can set your own log? `ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", "/tmp/php-error.log");
error_log( "Hello, errors!" );` You already know your code works, so people would have to take a wild guess as to what's wrong with the environment it doesn't work in without error logs. My guess is the font is missing.

Comment: @mkaatman The font isn't missing as I said, I can download it by accessing it in my browser. I added your code and nothing happened (no folder created / no error displayed).

Comment: Just for kicks, on localhost if you change the font name to something invalid, does the behavior match? Are PHP versions the same? It's crazy that you can install things but you don't have access to the logs.

Comment: @mkaatman On my server, here is what I get actually : http://prntscr.com/fjxxem - On my localhost, by changing the font name to something invalid, here is what I get : http://prntscr.com/fjxx8x

Comment: I thought otf needed imagefttext instead of imagettftext but I could be wrong on that.

Comment: @mkaatman Yes it work too on localhost, but I have the same problem on my debian, the image is only transparent, nothing else.

Comment: `$test = imagettftext(...); var_dump($test);` see if imagettftext is returning false in either environment.

Comment: @mkaatman by adding it after $test = imagettftext(...); I get this : http://prntscr.com/fjxzz9 - And by adding it at the last line of my php code I get this : http://prntscr.com/fjxzuv

Comment: Oh my mistake, you'll need to exit; immediately after var_dump to get the text and call this script directly if you're not already. `$test = imagettftext(...); var_dump($test);exit;`

Comment: @mkaatman by addint it after $test = imagettftext(...) I get "bool(false)"

Comment: In both the working and broken environments it gives false?

Comment: @mkaatman Oh sorry, in localhost I get this : https://pastebin.com/GiBtLycq

Comment: Alright, so we have verified that call is failing. The reasons could be: The font doesn't exist in the correct location, the font doesn't have the correct permissions, there's some version difference in libraries and that particular font can't be read. Maybe try a ttf font and see if you get different behavior.

Comment: @mkaatman No, same problem with ttf font + bool(false)

Comment: Can you set `ini_set('display_errors', '1');error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of that script and comment out the header, imagepng, imagedestroy lines and see if it gives you any errors?

Comment: I get this : 
Warning: imagettftext(): Could not find/open font in /var/www/html/includes/captcha.php on line 18 - But I don't understand why because the font exists, I can access it and it download ..

Comment: The font is in the same directory as the script? Temporarily set the permissions on it to 777. I'm kind of running out of ideas but I feel special knowing my first guess was correct!

Comment: Yes font is in the same directory and permissions set to 777 : http://prntscr.com/fjy51b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, you made me go find that font and run it locally. :)

I had the same error you're having until...

Drumroll please.

I added ./ to the path.
`$font = "./Inversionz.otf";`

Comment: Omg lol .. Thanks you a lot for your time and for your help !